# Create a Non-Angular library in an Angular application

Tags: angular, npm, angular6

I need to develop a typescript library in my **Angular** project and publish it to npm later. I learned that in Angular 6 I could use `ng generate library` to generate an npm ready library and be able to write and test the library in my application at the same time.

But in my case, the library will be a simple typescript file with some classes wrapped inside. It's not an Angular library since no components or services will be involved. I hope to develop it in my application because I still need the application to provide the data and test the results.

Can I still use `ng generate library` to do that? Like generate a non-angular library in my Angular application?

Comment: `ng generate library` will generate an Angular library. Could you add the classes as an Angular service so they could be dependency injected when they are used by the Angular app?

Comment: @DeborahK Not really, the library will be used to generate some angular services but it isn't an Angular service itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Better to use a [typescript starter library](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter) as a base for a non-angular typescript library which you plan on publishing to npm.

Because angular already supports a mono-repo format (mostly), you can keep the library in the same repo as your angular app. I use [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/) (and `yarn` instead of `npm`) to help facilitate this.

The repo structure I use is

```
apps/
  - app_1_name/
    - app/
    - e2e/
    - package.json
  - app_2_name/
    - app/
    - e2e/
    - package.json
libs/
  - lib_1_name/
package.json
angular.json
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, for typescript starter library, are you saying I can develop the library in the angular app by keeping the library in the  same repo? or do I have to develop it somewhere else and then use it from npm?

Comment: @Viv I'm saying you can develop the library for your angular app in the same repo as your angular app. If you want, you can use the library without publishing to NPM. You can also publish it to NPM and use it that way. Since your library is not an angular module though, better to use the typescript starter library (or another typescript starter library) as the base (rather than use `ng g library` as the base).