# Do I need to create an Angular library to publish a simple TS class that references Angular classes

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I have an existing Typescript class named `APIResponse` used in one Angular project that I would like to make available as an NPM package so that I can use it other projects.  The class is not an Angular artifact (`Service`, `Component`, etc.).  I think I only need to create a "standard" Typescript package, rather than generating an Angular library, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788129/create-a-non-angular-library-in-an-angular-application) seems to support that.

However, the `APIResponse` class does reference the Angular class `HttpErrorResponse` from `@angular/common/http`.

Does referencing this class mean that I need to create an Angular library, or do I just need to add a dependency to an Angular package in `package.json`?  And if so, which one?

This is the first time I've tried to publish an NPM package, so I'm still learning some of the language and terminology associated with this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can publish normal `TypeScript` packages to `NPM registry` without Angular. [This short medium](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm-89d93ff7bccd) blog can be helpful for your first `Ts` package.

As far as `Angular` is concerned in the context of your question, yes I think you need to use  `@Angular/common` to take advantage of `HttpErrorResponse` Which is part of Angular `HttpClientModule` which is part of [@Angular/common](https://angular.io/api/common/http)

There is a tendency to avoid publishing to NPM registry unless you need to. This is because of many pitfalls (versioning related problems).

I am not sure if you heard of [Nx orchestration system](https://nx.dev/) for monorepos. It is an awesome tool that helps big as well as small and medium sized projects to manage shared logic, UI components, and utilities (your case) between multiple apps (even from different frameworks say same `Interface` or `Class` shared between `Angular` and `Vue`).

So the same concept of `NPM libs` but locally shared between different projects in the same repository (you can also publish them via `nx`). It is super fast, clean and powerful tool to handle such issues. I have tried it and it is incredible when it comes to reusability.